# Word and Excel compatibility with microsoft office

Tags: ms-office

is your product compatible with office 2004 for macintosh?

Comment: To what product are you referring?

Comment: You may wish to consider rephrasing your question and including more information, there isn't enough context to know what product you are discussing and/or what issues you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

For office compatibility between Windows and Mac, take a look at:

http://www.haverford.edu/acc/docs/software/msoffice/office2007compatibility.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_2004_for_Mac

Comment: first link is broken, but second is fine.